# Good references on SPF, DMARC, DKIM, etc

Tags: spf, dkim, dmarc

please recommend some good source material mainly on spf but dmarc, dkim will be nice too.
The information that I have found on the web so far treats the subject too generally, or are instructions on how to configure the above with a specific service provider.
I would really like to understand the topic, so I am asking for help.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an article that I wrote on the subject: https://explained-from-first-principles.com/email/#domain-authentication

Comment: Thank you, I wish there were more people like this on stackoverflow